# Is there an adjectival or adverbial form of "legacy"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, derivational-morphology

For example:

> This process orders entries in a <*word*-ic> way     *(adjective)*
>   This process orders entries <*word*-ically>     *(adverb)*

My first thought was *legacical(ly)*, but a quick Google search reveals that isn't (yet) a word.

If there isn't a direct form, is there a similar adjective or adverb that can be used in a context like the one above?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or an adverb? ***Legacy*** as an adjective means: 
Denoting or relating to software or hardware that has been superseded but is difficult to replace because of its wide use. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/legacy.

Comment: This processes orders the old way.  This uses the legacy order processing system.

Comment: @Josh61 I am indeed looking for an adverb, see my example context.

Comment: *Legacical* is an adjectival form. *Legacically* would be an adverbial form. But actually, your example sentence does require an adjective (or an attributive noun, like *legacy*). Are you really asking for an adverb?

Comment: An adverbial form of _legacy_ would sound rather legacilly…

Comment: Legacical sounds very off. In my opinion, I would say legatial, but I'm not sure whether that the correct morphological change before the suffix should be c->t.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that is correct, my palm has collided with my forehead.  Thinking about it more, I was looking for both. I have decided to throw caution to the wind and use *legacical* and *lecgacically*, if you post that as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: In addition to *legacy itself*, the OED licenses both *legatary* and *legate* as adjectives meaning something like *like or relating to a legacy*, though it marks the adjectival use of the former *rare* and of the latter *obsolete*.  I think *legatary* could easily, if not elegantly, be extended to adverbial *legatarily*.

Comment: It should be made explicit that the question is specifically about the use of *legacy* in the jargon of software developers (that is not the primary use of the word).

Comment: In computing and IT, a thing is or is not a legacy system, program, etc. There is no such thing as entering stuff in a legacy way. This process orders entries as the legacy system did or would.

Answer (score 2):

'Legacy' is the adjectival form of 'legacy'.

> This process orders entries in a legacy way.

If you're hip enough, you can even use 'legacy' as the adverbial form of 'legacy'.

> This process orders entries *legacy*

Comment: Hip? Yours is the only example I can find on the internet. How is that trendy?

Answer (score -1):

I think that the adjectival and, by extension, the adverbial form of legacy should be *legatial* and *legatially* respectively. This choice is based off the establishment of existential, gladiatorial, etc.

Words ending in the *-ial* suffix
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ial

The *-ial* suffix is a very simple suffix of converting nouns into adjectives.

However, many words ending *acy* tend to change *-cy* to *-te*:

> degeneracy->degenerate
>
> celibacy->celibate
>
> articulacy->articulate

Others change to *-tic*, because *-cracy*, meaning rule, is the suffix in these words:

> bureaucracy->bureaucratic
>
> autocracy->autocratic
>
> aristocracy->aristocratic

Finally, there are a few that add the *-ious* suffix:

> contumacy->contumacious
>
> efficacy->efficacious
>
> fallacy->fallacious

Finally, there is one that has, from what I can tell, no direct adjectival form (conspiracy) but whose closest adjective is conspiratorial, which comes more directly from conspirator. OED2 does have conspiratious (def: Addicted to conspiring) and conspirative (def: Engaged in, involving, or characterized by conspiracy).

http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/acy/

Now, that leaves *legate*, *legacious*, and *legative*, excluding *legatial*. Legate already exists as a noun with a different meaning, although it could be used as an adjective. Legative, too, exists as a an adjective derived from the previous legate. Legacious has no precedence as a word and could very well be coined for such an instance, and the *-ly* suffix can be easily slapped on to make *legaciously*.

Comment: There’s also _legatary_ (“of or pertaining to a bequest”), which is probably about as close as you’ll get to the current meaning of _legacy_ with a word from the same etymological group. Much more straightforwardly than any of these adjectives, though, is simply using _legacy_ as a noun adjunct. Won’t work adverbially, but sounds fine adjectivally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Personally, I'd rather have an actual adjective than a nominal modifier, as certain adjectival suffixes create nuances. As for "closest to it…", yes, however, a simple coinage solves the problem of its lack of both adjective and adverb.

Answer (score -3):

Using "legacy" as an adjective is not "hip." It is indicative of shortcut laziness by millennials. The words "historical" or "discontinued" are more appropriate.

Comment: At least with reference to software (which the OP is talking about), neither historical nor discontinued means the same thing as [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system#Problems_posed_by_legacy_computing). If you're going to accuse people of being lazy, you shouldn't be lazy yourself — at least take the trouble to pick a word that means somewhere in the vicinity of the same thing (*antiquated* might work).

Comment: 'Legacy software' arguably uses 'legacy' as an attributive noun. This would then be the same usage as 'football manager', 'cricket bat' and the like.